# How to keep page content from scrolling without disabling scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

Alright so I'm really stumped by this one. How can I lock the page's scroll position to a specific value? I can't use `overflow: hidden;` on the body, because that prevents scroll events from firing entirely. I can't use `scrollTo(0,0)` every time the scroll event fires, because that causes a terrible stuttering effect.

What can I do? How can I lock the scroll at a specific spot? I've been scouring the internet and I've found nothing. A friend and I have been working on this for like an hour and can't think of anything at all. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: I'd like to achieve an effect identical to what is shown on this page: https://www.apple.com/ie/macbook-pro-16/

Comment: Wouldn't *locking* the page scroll value have the same effect as `overflow: hidden`; as the `scroll` event only fires when scrolling has actually occurred? If you need to know if the user is attempting to scroll then you could use the [wheel event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event).

Comment: You should add a [mcre] that shows HTML structure, CSS, and the desired effect.

Comment: did you try "position:fixed;"

Comment: create a new div and add all the content you don`t want to scroll inside it and give it a class. and in CSS, select that div and write what i suggested.

Comment: As i see `position: sticky;`, but whole animation more complex.